# What is the infinite series of $2\int \frac{e^x - 1}{7x} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

My typical approach to finding the $n$-th derivative for a Taylor series is to find a few derivatives and notice a pattern.

However, for this function,
$$2\int\frac{e^x – 1}{7x} dx$$
the first derivative is obviously 
$2 \frac{e^x - 1}{7x}$ but after that it gets very messy.

What is the infinite series of this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to find those derivatives.

You have
$$
2\frac{e^x-1}{7x} = \frac 2 {7x} (e^x-1) = \frac 2 {7x} \cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac 2 7 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}.
$$
Now integrate term by term.

Comment: How do you know that 2(e^x – 1)/(7x) = 2/7x * ∑n=1∞ (x^n)/n! ?
i know that e^x = ∑n=0∞ (x^n)/n! but it's not immediately apparent to me of how that formula can be applied here.

Comment: @HenryWalsh : Because $\displaystyle e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ and consequently $\displaystyle e^x-1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}. \qquad$